# Add custom character at the end of custom enumerate item but remove in crossreference

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I want to make a custom enumerate item which ends with Dot(.). But problem here is that when I use this item in crossref it also show the Dot(.). But I want to remove the Dot(.) when using in crossref.

```
\begin{enumerate} [leftmargin=*, wide=0pt, label={\textbf{$\boldsymbol{Case} \ $\arabic*.}}]
\item \label{item:case1} this is a sample.
\end{enumerate}
```

Now I want this:

[image]

But getting this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `\textbf{$\boldsymbol{Case}` supposed to do?

Comment: You can use the key `ref=Cas~\arabic*`.

Comment: @leandriis just to make it italic.

Comment: @ZeeshanAliQureshi: Please do not use math mode to get italic text. Instead you can use `\itshape` or `\textit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Bernard mentioned in the comments, the `ref` key from `enumitem` is meant to do that. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[
    leftmargin=*, 
    wide=0pt, 
    label={\textbf{\textit{Case}\ \arabic*.}},
    ref={\textbf{\textit{Case}\ \arabic*}}
]
\item \label{item:case1} this is a sample.
\end{enumerate}
Referencing \ref{item:case1} here.
\end{document}
```

[image]